# SQL query to filter out results based on count

Tags: mysql

I have the following table `ratings`, with columns as:

`rating_id`, `prod_id`, `rating`, `buyer`, `status`, `prod_type` [`rating_id` is unique]

The `rating` column takes values from `1` to `5` and `buyer` takes only 2 values `0` or `1`.

I want to write an SQL query that retrieves all those products with their average rating from buyers who are `1` such that the number of buyers who are `1` are greater than 5 for a particular product.

For example, I want the result to be like:

```
`prod_id` `avg(rating)`  `count(*)`
ksks       3.2            6
kglgkj     4.0            8
jfkfj      2.0            13
```

I had written the following query but it is not working:

**SELECT prod_id, avg(rating), count(`*`) WHERE buyer = 1 AND count(`*`) > `5` GROUP BY prod_id;**

I am getting the error as **invalid use of group function**.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You can't use agregate functions in where clause. If you want filter the result, use HAVING clause http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-having.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use [`HAVING`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) to check for the `COUNT`. Use the following query:

```
SELECT prod_id, AVG(rating), COUNT(*) 
WHERE buyer = 1 
GROUP BY prod_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 5
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use HAVING for this:

```
SELECT prod_id, avg(rating), count(*) 
WHERE buyer = 1 
GROUP BY prod_id
HAVING count(*) > 5
```